# Color is not defined D3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to draw a line chart with D3.js when I got the error color is not defined. However when I look it up in tutorials it is not defined anywhere. Should the color be defined in an other way? What I do is basically read the data file and set the necessary components for my chart. I am a beginner with D3 and I am not sure if my coding style is correct.

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function (error, data) {

            console.log("inital data", data);

            var labelvar = "OutDistance";
            var varNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) { return key !== labelvar });

            color.domain(varNames);

            var seriesData = varNames.map(function (name) {
                return {
                    name: name,
                    values: data.map(function (d) {
                        return { name: name, label: d[labelvar], value: +d[name] };
                    })
                };
            });

            console.log("seriesData", seriesData);

            x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d.OutDistance;
            }));
            y.domain([
                d3.min(seriesData, function (c) {
                    return d3.min(c.values, function (d) { return d.value; });
                }),
                d3.max(seriesData, function (c) {
                    return d3.max(c.values, function (d) { return d.value; })
                })
            ]);

            var series = d3.selectALL(".series").data(seriesData)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class" , "series");

            series.append("path")
            .attr("class","line")
            .attr("d" , function(d) {return line(d.values);})
            .style("stroke" , function(d){return color(d.name);})
            .style("stroke-width", "4px")
            .style("fill" , "none");

            var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
            .x(function(d){return x(d.label) + x.rangeBand() / 2 ;})
            .y(function(d) {return y(d.value);});

        });
```

Comment: `However when I look it up in tutorials it is not defined anywhere`... Really? Which tutorials are you looking at? [1](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10), [2](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain), [3](http://bl.ocks.org/aaizemberg/78bd3dade9593896a59d), [4](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/16/learning-d3-part-6-scales-colors), [5](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/), [6](http://jonathansoma.com/tutorials/d3/color-scale-examples/)....

Comment: @Mark http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs

Comment: In that particular example `color` is defined as: `var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#001c9c","#101b4d","#475003","#9c8305","#d3c47c"]);`  You can see the full code he is using [here](https://github.com/sghall/d3-multi-series-charts/blob/master/lib/chart.js#L21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use d3 colors, you can declare them in two ways.

1) Using d3 categorical colors

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

Reference: http://bl.ocks.org/aaizemberg/78bd3dade9593896a59d

2) Using d3 linear scales.

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 0, 1])
    .range(["red", "white", "green"]);
```